# Unable to login to EC2 (AWS) using Putty

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, putty

I want to login to the instance i created on Amazon Web Services. I get the following error.

```
login as: root
Server refused our key
Using keyboard-interactive authentication.
Password:
```

I dont know what to enter as Password. I have given the privatekey created from PuttyGen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The created SSH key was wrong. The key happends to be SSH 1. not SSH2. For me it worked for root.

Answer (score 15):

The username of Amazon AMI is difference depend on the AMI creator,

for Amazon AMI , user ec2-user
for Ubuntu AMI , user ubuntu

You may search from the ami-id to see what is the default username of that AMI. Please ensure that this key you use is the private key for the public key which you put to key-binding when you created the instance.

Answer (score 3):

Try logging in as ec2-user.  On the instances I have tried root login was disabled by default.